# argmin homogeneous function

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus, optimization

We consider
$$
p^\star = \text{argmin}_{p\in \mathbb{R}^n} \quad 1/2f(p)^2- p\cdot g
$$
where $f: \mathbb{R}^n\mapsto \mathbb{R}$  is a (smooth) 1-homogeneous and
$g \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is constant.

We introduce 
$$
\pi^\star = \text{argmax}_{\pi | f(\pi)=1} \quad  \pi\cdot g
$$

Then, is this statement is true

$$
p^\star = \left(\pi^\star \cdot g\right) \pi^\star
$$

?

---

**EDIT: proposed solution:**
Ok let assume $f(p) \neq 0$.

We have

$$
p^\star = argmin_{p\in\mathbb{R}^n} 1/2f(p)^2-(p\cdot g)
$$
$$
=argmin_{p\in \mathbb{R}^n} \min_{p|f(p)=1} 1/2f(p)^2-f(p)(p/f(p)\cdot g)
$$
$$
=argmin_{p\in \mathbb{R^n}} 1/2f(p)^2-f(p) \max_{\pi|f(\pi)=1}(\pi\cdot g)
$$

Let denote $\max_{\pi|f(\pi)=1}(\pi\cdot g) = \pi^\star$.
$$
p^\star = argmin_{p\in \mathbb{R}^n} 1/2f(p)^2-f(p)(\pi^\star\cdot g)
$$

then it is not difficult to see that 
$$
p^\star = (\pi^\star\cdot g)\pi^{\star}
$$

what do you think ?

I am not looking for a proof that would work with precise statement. I want at least to know if I didn't have any reasoning mistakes like this step:
$$
argmin_{p\in \mathbb{R}^n} h= argmin_{p\in \mathbb{R}^n} \min_{p|h(p)=1} h
$$
but I ignore some extreme case where the result doesn't hold.

?

Comment: How would you like to cope with $f(p)=0$ (argmax over empty set), when argmin has multiple solutions, or when argmax has multiple solutions ($g=0$)? Are there any nonlinear smooth 1-homogeneous functions for which argmax exists?

Comment: ok, what if first we look for conditions when this result is true, don't we ?